# Hammer.js not working for mobile but works on desktop

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(document.getElementById('search-panel'));
        hammertime.on('pan', function(ev) {
            alert('pan');
            document.getElementById('productsList').style.color = 'red'
        });

        hammertime.on('pinch', function(ev) {
            alert('pinch');
        });
```

In console this code in dekstop work but in mobile telephon doesn't . 
What's problem? Help me please. 
Maybe options pass ?

Comment: Without Hammer, does alert('...'); show anything on this phone?

Comment: no alert,no change color

Comment: So Hammer.js isn't relevant? Basically, the problem is - alert() isn't supported by the phone browser?

Comment: @zloctb If you can give us more detailed information what kind of smartphone you used would be great. such as Android or iOS, the OS version, the browser you use, etc. It might help to investigate the problem.